# How to render a markers when they are useful?

Tags: react-native, google-maps-markers, markers

EXAMPLE

Take the case in which you want to render a map with markers behaving differently when the map is zoomed in and when it is not.
I need to to this when I mode the map witha zomm, the markers are ploting in the map, not alll markers in component did mount...
vlow some code, after the link of the code:

```
renderMarkers() {
return this.state.isLoading
  ? null
  : this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
      const coords = {
        latitude: JSON.parse(marker.latitude),
        longitude: JSON.parse(marker.longitude),
      };
      return (
        <MapView.Marker
          onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
          ref={mark => (marker.mark = mark)}
          key={index}
          title={'Parada'}
          description={marker.hora}
          coordinate={coords}>
          <Image
            onPress={e => this.onPressMarker(e, index)}
            source={
              this.state.selectedMarkerIndex === index
                ? markerImage2
                : markerImage2
            }
            style={styles.icon}
          />
        </MapView.Marker>
      );
    });
```

}

The right way to do so is to check if the map is zoomed into the MapView component and then pass a prop isMapZoomed to each marker so that it can behave accordingly.

like bellow:

```
render() {
return (
    <MapView>
        {this.state.pois && this.state.pois.map(marker => (
            <CustomMarker
                key={marker.id}
                isZoomed={this.isMapZoomed(this.state.displayedRegion)}
            />
        ))}
    </MapView>
);
```

}

How can I implement this in my code? I need to render more than a thousand markers, and the app crash, any ideia to make this possible?

here is the full snack code:

https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/maps-geoloation

if you want more information visit this site:

https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/four-tips-optimize-react-native-map-performance-user-experience

Answer (score 0):

[onRegionChange](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) event, you can use `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` for know map zoom lvl, but you need implement your own algorithm... or use clustering: [react-native-map-clustering](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-map-clustering)

Comment: In my case i wanr to render the maskers just when the screen is in that area, and have a limite by zoom..

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/clusters please see this snack, what is my wrong?

Comment: looks like a problem with the library, then last commit was 2 years ago